# Record video from camera and get frame number on demand

Tags: linux, ubuntu, video, recording, avconv

I'm using avconv at the moment to store the input of my camera as an video. This works fine. Now i'm asking myself if it is possible to get the current frame number at a particular time of the video which is recording .

For example :
I run `avconv -f video4linux2 -r 25 -i /dev/video0 ...` to record the video.
Now an other command should work like : `getCurrentFrameNumber...` and return the frame number of the moment the function was called.

A solution which i could imagine, but not implenent is to pipe out/extract the frame number from the running avconv into file. Then i could just easily grep it out of the file. But i do not know how accurate this method would be.

I'm not dependent to use avconv, if there are other **commandline**  tools which can record and solve my problem, it would be a great solution,too. Also i will just record one video and not multiple at the same time, if this helps.